# Upgrading my ebike battery to give more speed and longer range

Tags: power-supply, power

I am in the early stages of trying to understand how to do this, so if you're kind enough to reply, please answer in simple terms if that's at all possible.

I want to add cells to my electric bike battery pack to increase the speed and the range. The speed is less important than the range - but a bit more would be nice. I've opened the case and found 5 banks of 8 x 18650 li-ion cells in there. I know that each bank is connected in series, with the cells in each bank connected in parallel. The bike is a Freego Hawk 36v. I have enough slots for another 20 cells (ie 2.5 banks). Would anyone know what is the best way to configure them to get much more range, and a bit of extra speed if possible. The existing cells are Samsung ICR 18650 26H li-ion, 2600mA, 3.65v.

Comment: The cells in parallel can be though of as just one large 3.65 cell. You are saying that you have 5 banks in series, where each bank is basically a giant 3.65V cell. But that only adds up to 18V or so. So how is it a 36V bike? Something doesn't add up.

Answer (score 2):

To increase the speed you need to increase the voltage. To do this you need to be sure that *both* your motor and your controller are rated for this. It is very unlikely that your motor is rated for > 36 V so you will burn it out.

[image]

*Figure 1. The Freego Hawk with rear-wheel hub motor.*

If the motor is in the hub (which it is in the Hawk) then that leaves you with no ability to speed it up. My Kalkhoff / Panasonic drives the chain of the bike from a motor below the front chainwheel so I was able to reduce the rear sprocket from 21 to 19 teeth to gain more speed.

I can't comment on the batteries other than to say 0.5 of a battery bank isn't going to be any good. I imagine you're going to have trouble with charging.

Answer (score 1):

Safest is probably to add an "auxilliary battery" completely separate from your existing one and switch to this as a reserve when needed.

As speed increases vehicle energy %age increasingly goes into combating "windage" as air drag increases with velocity cubed. If you can reduce effective frontal area and drag-coefficient you may achieve range improvements as good as is possible with the available extra cells.
Going slower also pays dividends when distance matters. A decrease in speed by 10% decreases drag energy needs by 100 x (1- 0.9^3) = 27% and probably increases range in average conditions by a similar amount at speeds above say 15 kph or so.

**But first ...**

The main issue with extending power packs of this sort is that, if you do not have a good understanding of what you are doing then there is a reasonable (or unreasonable) possibility that you will destroy some or all of the battery pack, the controller the bike miscellaneous bystanders and/or yourself.

Lithium ion cells have a charming mode known colloquially as "vent with flame". 
This can be triggered by a range of unlikely events and if enough energy is available can resemble a slow hand grenade detonating. Even more and it may seem to resemble a moderately vast nad grenade, although actual explosion is generally absent. To get close to genuine explosion one may throw copious water on the comflagration which encourages the now gaseous lithium metal and perhaps released Hydrogen to perform a passable HG explosion.

In your case you have energy of roughly

Vcell x Ah-cell x cell-quantity Watt hours of energy or
Vcell x Ah-cell x seconds/hour x cell-quantity Joule.

Here = 3.6 x 2.6 x 40 =~ 375 Watt hours or
~= 1,350,000 Joule or Watt seconds
= 1,350 kilowatt seconds of energy.
or about 1800 horsepower seconds.
Spread this over say 10 seconds and assume only 50% gets made available and you have ~= 90 horsepower x 10 seconds of power delivery.
This would be not too foul if trying to make a mini electric dragster but not so good if its used to spread flaming chaos far and near.

So, you need to be **careful**.
You need to understand what you are doing.

---

**That said,**

Your present battery is described as an 8S5P arrangement (5 parallel strings of 8 batteries in series).

You should notionally be able to add additional strings of 8 cells in series.
in your case 2 strings x 8 cells  each, giving an 8S7P battery.

However:

Batteries added are presumably not the same age of history of the existing ones and may be different types. This can often lead to imbalance problems, early cell death, possibly early whole battery death and possibly slow handgrenades.

The 8S2P sub-battery could be used with a separate switch to provide a 'reserve tank'. The discharge rating of the cells may make this a bad idea. You should provide links to battery and bike data.

The existing 8S strings are hopefully provided with a means of balancing during charging. How any new strings can be added to the balancing system or if they can is TBD. Adding unbalanced strings is "unwise".

Your present battery capacity, assuming the same cells in current battery as you describe above is 2.6Ah x 5 strings = 13 Ah nominal. You could consider selling your existing cells and making a whole new battery. You can buy eg very long cycle life LiFePO4 batteries. These may come as separate cells or as 12V batteries. 3 x 12V x 20 Ah batteries would give about 40% more energy capacity than your existing cells. 3 x 40Ah x 12V = 3 x existing capacity. Weight is low compared to lead acid and slightly higher than LiIon per Wh.

As 'transistor' notes, speed PROBABLY comes from voltage - although it is possible that your system is speed limited below what it is capable of at the supplied voltage.

Note that liIon cells have Vout range of say 3V to 4.2V/cell so 8 in series gives 24V - 33.6 V. To get 36V with 8 cells you'd need V_cell = 36V/8 = 4.5V which is above what you can safely get from LiIon cells. ie the 36V is nominal. If the motor and controller can stand genuine 36V then you MAY be able to add one more cell per string.
9 x 4.2 = 37.8 V.
36/9 = 4V.
You'd REALLY need to check if say 38V for a while after charging was safe or might lead to slow hand grenading.

Charging a battery with 9 series cells is not hard but may annoy your existing charger.

Answer (score 1):

The safest method is to buy a second battery pack or make one just like you already have. Switch and charge them as needed. Range is a big key so if it's a bicycle you can normally pedal to help assist the battery and double your range without much work. 
Adding  more cells to the pack could be a problem with the motor voltage limit but most can handle more. It can also cause charging problems. So if you really want more range and speed you should buy a new high end model E bicycle. With lots of battery progress they cost less and go further.

Comment: OK thanks - but what do you mean by "With lots of battery progress they cost less and go further" - surely a bike with a longer range (ie a larger Ah battery) costs more?  My Hawk cost just over £1000 a few weeks ago. If I tried to sell it as second-hand I'd lose hundreds, and wouldn't be able to afford a bike with a higher spec. - which I'm sure are a lot more. The shop I bought it from don't do part-exchange. But thanks for taking an interest.

Answer (score 1):

I'm relatively new to electrical two-wheeled transportation and I'd like to share my experiences and get feedback on what I tried. I live in China, and as a foreigner, have not passed the driving test here. An electric scooter seems like the best and fastest way to get around with the least hassle as one does not need a license.

After 1-2 months of riding it around, it was great, but I also wanted more distance between charges, more speed, more power going uphill etc... I guess I'm being a little bit greedy, because it's already a pretty good bike. Everything being in Chinese, I am not 100% certain, but I believe my bike should have a 60V 20Ah sealed lead acid battery (SLA). The bike I have is more like a motor-cycle, it weighs 90kg, and doesn't have any pedals. It has a dashboard display that shows information like the speed, the distance travelled, the remaining charge (in bars) on the battery, indicating when you need to plug it in. It can go 25-30km before I lose the first bar (I was told it can go 70km between charges, by the salesperson, but have never tested it) with a top speed of about 40km/h, though the speedometer regularly shows over 50km/h when the battery is freshly charged. The fastest I'm able to clock on the speedometer is 56km/h on flat ground on power-level 3. But my GPS tells me I'm going just under 40km/h, and I trust the GPS more.

On the charger it is printed 60V 20Ah, and it looks like an oversized laptop charger. The way these kinds of bikes are charged in China is that you park next to a wall outlet, plug one side of the charger into the wall and the other end into your bike, the battery is not removable by the user. (upto) 8 hours later the charger cuts down to a trickle changing from red to green. The charger is big and clunky and looks rather cheaply built. The seat of my bike can be opened with some storage under it where the charger and lock and few other things can be kept.

After thinking about how to increase my range/speed/power, I decided to buy a Lithium ion battery online (JD.com). I got a 60V20Ah lithium battery for 1768 RMB (about US$270) https://item.jd.com/4523101.html and a Li-ion charger for 120 RMB https://item.jd.com/3138969.html. The Li-ion battery has the same kind of charging/discharging port that the bike has. My idea was to try to connect the Li-ion battery in parallel with the existing SLA battery. So I bought a cable that I thought would allow me to connect the batteries in parallel https://item.jd.com/13936790374.html. Unfortunately, this cable connects the batteries in series and I had to cut and reattach the cable to connect positive to postive and negative to negative. In addition, I bought a useful little voltmeter (https://item.jd.com/10663359922.html) that connects into the charging port on the bike which (I think) connects directly to the terminals of the SLA battery.

With the voltmeter, I could tell that after a full charge the SLA battery had a voltage of 68.5 V, while the Li-ion battery had a voltage of 71.4V. Based on this, I think that the Li-ion has 17 cells in series, with a nominal voltage of 3.7*17=62.9V. The difference between 68.5 and 71.4 seemed to be close enough that I could just plug the two batteries in parallel using my cut-and-reattached cable which I did. One point to be careful on, is that when reconnecting the cables, one must make very sure that they are connected in parallel and not anti-parallel which would short the positive to negative terminals of both batteries which would be really BAD. Use a multimeter to ensure the positive is connected to positive and negative to negative. Plugging one end of the cable into the Li-ion battery and the other end into the charging port of my bike completes the parallel circuit of the batteries.

So far, so good. The slightly higher voltage from the Li-ion battery pulls the voltage up when under load, and I'm now able to clock over 60km/h on the speedometer (in reality it's still in the 45km/h region). The motor and the controller of the bike seem to be able to take the extra amps/watts, nothing is burning or smoking. The battery just fits nicely under my seat and I can comfortably run my home-made cable from the Li-ion battery to the charging port on the bike to connect the two batteries in parallel.

I'd like to get the opinion of any battery experts out there, whether connecting batteries of different chemistries in parallel like this will cause any problems? I unplug and charge each battery separately with its own special charger designed for that chemistry. So far during the discharging (usage), I have yet to drop below 5 bars (which corresponds to 60V) on the dashboard before recharging, so I'm not pushing either battery near its limits. I don't think I'm doing any damage to either battery, but would like to know what others think.

In my mind, connecting the batteries in parallel means that for a given travel distance, the depth of discharge (DOD) is half of what it would be otherwise, meaning the strain on each battery is half. I expect that this will lengthen the life of both batteries.

If the above is correct, I think that connecting a second Li-ion battery in parallel with the in-built SLA battery is an ideal solution for my needs. It gives me the increased range, increased power (acceleration), increased top speed, reduced stress on the batteries reduced DoD and reduced charging time, since the batteries are discharged less between recharges.

Some points to note with a disclaimer: I am just sharing what I tried and seems to have worked pretty well so far for me. If you attempt this, but don't know what you're doing, you could cause some serious damage, so do so at your own risk. Things that come to my mind in particular that you want to watch out for: Make absolutely sure the positive terminal of one battery is connected to the positive terminal of the other battery and same for the negative. Getting this wrong could be quite devastating. At the very least, sparks and a burnt out cable, with worse case scenarios including, fire, venting and possible explosion (I'm thinking of the Li-ion battery in particular). I would also recommend charging each battery separately with the chargers designed for those batteries rather than charging the batteries together with one charger. When you reconnect the batteries in parallel, some current will flow from the higher voltage battery to the lower voltage battery, equalizing the voltages somewhere in between. So one should ensure this voltage difference between the two batteries is not too large before reconnecting them, to avoid large currents flowing between the batteries (eg: do not connect at 60V and a 48V battery in parallel). I believe this should not be a problem for the batteries if this is observed. Perhaps others have some advice to share on this.